# Extend dynamically loaded module class in browser

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, es6-class

Say I have a JS file that exports class `Cat`, for example:

```
class Cat {

}
export default Cat;
```

The URL to this file is dynamic and can anything, for example: `https://my-domain/cat.js` or `https://another-domain/something/something/cat.js`. Content security issues are resolved, and the file can always be loaded.

Now I need to import class Cat to another file, so I do:

```
const catURL = 'https://my-domain/cat.js';
const Cat = await import(url);

class SuperCat extends Cat {

}
export default SuperCat;
```

However I need to define `catURL` dynamically. How do I do so, and is it possible at all? I tried to save `catURL` in some global variable like `window.catURL =  'https://my-domain/cat.js'` and then do:

```
const catURL = window.catURL;
const Cat = await import(url);

class SuperCat extends Cat {

}
export default SuperCat;
```

but it doesn't work (since window is undefined there).

Not using any bundler, this is in-browser.

Thanks!

Comment: Using `import()` syntax is *meant* to be used for dynamic imports, so yes this is possible.

Comment: `window` shouldn't be undefined in a browser. How exactly are you running/importing this module?

Comment: `url` is `catURL` in your actual code, right?

Comment: I'm importing from catj.js via script type="module", and window is undefined for some reason, so is "this".